# Property 'catch' does not exist on type 'OperatorFunction<Response, Response>'

Tags: angular, rxjs

```
 <p> i have tried all these
     import {Observable,EMPTY,throwError} from 'rxjs' 
     import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
   //import 'rxjs/add/operator/map' 
   //import 'rxjs/Rx' 
    //import {map,catchError} from 'rxjs/operators' 
     import { } from "rxjs/operators";
      import { map, filter, catchError, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators'</p>



public isLoggedIn():Observable<boolean>{
  return this.http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
    .pipe(map((res:Response)=> res)
    .catch((error:any)=>Observable.throw(error||'Server Error')))  
}
```

Comment: Hello prabhakar singh! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please consider inserting the code into your question instead of attaching screenshots of your code. Lastly, please consider posting the link of what appears to be a screenshot of a Stackblitz. Thanks!

Comment: use `catchError(()=>)`

Comment: tried but same error i am getting

Comment: what version of rxjs are you using?

Comment: Your post consists mostly of code! I suggest visiting [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to get a better insight on how to ask a solid question. A better explanation is necessary in order for others to offer you help (they 1st need to understand what the actual issue is). Hang in there. You'll be great at this. ;)

Answer (score 0):

In RxJS v6 you list the operators comma separated inside your `pipe()`

Also `catch` is now called `catchError`

Try this instead:

```
public isLoggedIn():Observable<boolean>{
  return this.http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1").pipe(
    map((res:Response)=> res),
    catchError((error:any)=>Observable.throw(error||'Server Error')))
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `CatcError` instead of `catch`
and You must return an observable from the `catchError` function!

**Modified Code:**

```
public isLoggedIn():Observable<boolean>{
  return this.http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1").pipe(
    map((res:Response)=> res),
    catchError((error)=>{return Observable.throw(error||'Server Error')})
  )
}
```